# Activity to Fragment sending data and access arraylist in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a `fragment` which is present in Bottom Navigation Activity. The `Fragments` contain the custom `recyclerview`. There is a comment button when i press it opens another activity for comments. Below is in the `RecyclerView` adapter.

```
    viewholder.commentlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
                //commenttofragment.clear();
                Intent comment = new Intent(fp, com.fooddoof.fuddict.comment.class);
                int id = dusers.get(position).getId();
                int comcount = dusers.get(viewholder.getAdapterPosition()).getCommentcount();
                comment.putExtra("id",id);
                comment.putExtra("ownerid",userid);
                comment.putExtra("maincommentposition",position);
                comment.putExtra("commentcountonposition", comcount);
                fp.startActivityForResult(comment,1);

        }
    });
```

In Comment activity after doing some tasks I need to send some values to this `fragment`. So I Override the `OnBackPressed` method. I have created a method in `Fragment` to receive it.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("maincommentcount",maincommentcount);
    args.putInt("maincommentposition", maincommentposition);
    FolowersPost f = new FolowersPost();
    f.getdatafromcomment(args);
    finish();
}
```

I receive it like below in `Fragment`.

```
public void getdatafromcomment(Bundle args)
{
    int count = args.getInt("maincommentcount");
    int p=args.getInt("maincommentposition",999999999);
    Log.e("Shiva","count--->"+count+"p--->"+p);

}
```

The Values are received but I need to access the `arraylist` in `Fragement` which is passed in `Adapter` for displaying the `recyclerView`. But I am not able to access it while I am coming back to `fragment` which is present in the method under `OnCreateView`. I tried with `OnResume` to access it but works for some time only. I have declared the `Arraylist` as global variable also.

Comment: do you want send data to fragment on comment activity's `onBackPressed` ??

Comment: @RumitPatel - I am able to send data from comment activity to fragment but i want to update the adapter in Fragment using the value i sent from comment activity. For this is  I need to access the arraylist which is present in the Fragment after data is received. I am not able to access arraylist  once i finish the activity.

Answer (score 0):

You are already using [`startActivityForResult.`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle)) now you just need to use [`onActivityResult.`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent))

But you just need to start activity from fragment instead of from adapter.

**`onClick` from fragment:**

```
Intent comment = new Intent(getActivity(), com.fooddoof.fuddict.comment.class);
startActivityForResult(comment, 1);
```

**`onBackPressed` in your comment activity:**

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        returnIntent.putExtra("maincommentcount",10);
        returnIntent.putExtra("maincommentposition",20);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
        finish();        
//        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

**`onActivityResult` in fragment:**

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                int mMaincommentcount = data.getIntExtra("maincommentcount", 0);
                int mMaincommentposition = data.getIntExtra("maincommentposition", 0);

                System.out.println("mMaincommentcount = " + mMaincommentcount + ", mMaincommentposition = " + mMaincommentposition);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am getting the values without the above option. Problem what i faced is i am not able to access the arraylist inside the method.

Comment: but according to my answer you will be able to access your arrayList in `onActivityResult.` for sure.

Comment: No I am not able to access it after finishing the activity.

Comment: do you use `startActivityForResult` from Fragment or from adapter?

Comment: yes.. Please check my questions for detail explanation

Comment: In your question, I can see you are using `startActivityForResult` from adapter. that you should not. you should use it from fragment.